# How would I convert this .NET string to UTF-8

Tags: c#, .net, utf

```
  var stringu = @"\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003eHello world";
```

Background here - I'm using HttpClient to request data, and am getting back a JSON string in UTF-8 (Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 is the the header on the response).

To simulate the content conversion I wrote this code

```
  var stringu = @"\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003eHello world";
  var ubytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringu);
  var asciibytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, ubytes);
  var ascii = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(asciibytes);
  Console.WriteLine(ascii);
  Console.ReadKey();
```

This does not work however.
I admit - I do not fully understand UTF-16/8 conversions (or even if I need to make it, considering I just output the returned bytes to a html file), so any help here is appreciated.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you want to get out as a result - I'd expect a JSON library to handle all of this for you.

Comment: Why use ascii? Why not UTF16? .NET's internal char type?

Comment: <br /><br />Hello world  - is the output I want on the console

Comment: @ColeJohnson The string shown is just a snippet of the UTF-8 string that is returned as the response of a http request

Comment: Here's a little tip. You _can't_ use <br/> in a console. It's not HTML. Also, that string could already be written. Your code just converts it to ASCII and then back to UTF-16 by casting it to a string.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I know that <br /> will not work on the console. What I have from my response is a UTF-8 string as shown. Ideally, the response's charset should've been UTF-16, but this I cannot control.

Comment: So your response would be a stream of bytes that are in UTF 8? If that's the case, then your question makes a lot more sense. I would just leave out the string "response". I'd also reccomend _against_ ASCII.

Comment: However, if what you were provided _was_ a string object, then it is _already_ in UTF16.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Agreed about the naming; this was just quick snippet code. stringu is a quoted string if you notice, if I remove the '@' I would get a UTF-16 encoded string as expected

Comment: I don't think you understand. ANY string in .NET is internally UTF16! Even if you convert it to ASCII. Converting it to ASCII just throws away the other information. The only way to get _actual_ UTF-8 is to use a byte array (`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)`). That will convert your UTF16 string into a UTF8 byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code it will help you

```
var ss = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape("\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003eHello world")
```

Comment: What library do you have to import?

Comment: Right click on "Reference" section of the project, Go to ".Net" tab and select `Microsoft.JScript`

Comment: If you did not notice, stringu in my example is a quoted string. Your example is an already encoded UTF-16 string, so no escaping is required. I tried the method with my string, it did not work.

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot at it though! :)